# Como trazer valor null consulta Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Tenho uma consulta sql onde traz o total de um valor inserido em uma data, porém quero demostrar no resultado as datas que geraram zero, mesmo não contendo informação no banco de dados, sempre pesquiso em um período e os dias são aleatórios tanto para pagamento, tando para dias que não contem dados.

```
SELECT DATA, 
       SUM(VALOR)
FROM TABELA1
WHERE CONTA = '176087'
GROUP BY DATA
```

Resultado:

```
DATA       | VALOR
02/10/2015 | 36312
05/10/2015 | 25382
06/10/2015 | 3655
```

Comment: Há o registro daquela data com o valor zerado ou não há a data na tabela?

Comment: as datas que não constam no resultado não tem no banco de dados, teria que demonstrar na consulta os dias que não tem com o valor zero, em ordem com os demais que contem os valores

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa implementar alguma funcionalidade que liste os dias entre as datas inicial e final:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ExplodeDates(@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime)
returns table as
return (
with 
 N0 as (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N0 t1, N0 t2)
,N2 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N1 t1, N1 t2)
,N3 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N2 t1, N2 t2)
,N4 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N3 t1, N3 t2)
,N5 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N4 t1, N4 t2)
,N6 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N5 t1, N5 t2)
,nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as num FROM N6)
SELECT DATEADD(day,num-1,@startdate) as thedate
FROM nums
WHERE num <= DATEDIFF(day,@startdate,@enddate) + 1
);
```

A partir daí, extraia os valores MIN e MAX das datas da sua consulta, e passe-as para a funcão:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.ExplodeDates('20151002','20151006') as d;
```

O resultado deste *statement* é o seguinte:

```
thedate
October, 02 2015 00:00:00
October, 03 2015 00:00:00
October, 04 2015 00:00:00
October, 05 2015 00:00:00
October, 06 2015 00:00:00
```

Utilize-o como agrupador na sua query original.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function